# pg_config not found while I have it installed

Tags: python, git, bash, postgresql, multicorn

I have installed postgresql development packages and I have it in C:/pgsql96 (in bin directory I have packages, such as pg_config, I also added the path to my environment variables. Now that I want to install Multicorn (a postgresql python package), I cloned the git repository of Multicorn in C:/Multicorn, and when I want to run make && make install command, I get the following error:

```
make: pg_config: Command not found
make: pythonpython:-config: Command not found
expr: syntax error
expr: syntax error
Python version is python:
./preflight-check.sh
which: no pg_config in (/mingw64/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/c/Windows/System32:/c/Windows:/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl)
No pg_config found in your path.
Please check if you installed the PostgreSQL development packages.
make: *** [Makefile:28: preflight-check] Error 1
```

I have python installed in my system because I have access to it from my command prompt (I run python --version and I see that I have it installed) but in MinGW bash which I am running make && make install, there is no python installed. 
Anyone knows how can I solve these problems:

1) pg_config in not in my path, although I added C:\pgsql96\bin to my system variables ( should it be added to user variables instead of system variavles? I also tried adding it to both environment variables!!) but the command:

```
which pg_config
```

returns me:

```
 no pg_config in (/mingw64/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/c/Windows/System32:/c/Windows:/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl)
```

2- I have access to python modules from my command prompt but I cannot access them from mingw bash, I need to work with mingw bash in order to be able to run make && make install commands. Can you please explain me when should I use command prompt and when should I use MinGW, and if there should be synchronization between these two?

**UPDATE 1:**
For the first problem that pg_config was not found, I added the path to my mingw/bin directory. However, I have another problem about `python.h`:

```
make: pythonpython:-config: Command not found
Python version is python:
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wendif-labels -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wformat-security -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -fexcess-precision=standard -O2    -I. -I./ -IC:/pgsql96/include/server -IC:/pgsql96/include/internal -I/c/Builds/postgresql/source/src/include/port/win32 -DEXEC_BACKEND  -IC:/pgsql96/include/server/port/win32  -c -o src/errors.o src/errors.c
In file included from src/errors.c:15:0:
src/multicorn.h:1:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
 #include "Python.h"
                    ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [<builtin>: src/errors.o] Error 1
```

**UPDATE 2:**

I added Python path to the configuration process, and here is result: ANOTHER ERROR:

```
$ make && make install
Python version is 2.7
[ -d sql ] || mkdir sql
[ -d src ] || mkdir src
touch directories.stamp
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wendif-labels -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wformat-security -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -fexcess-precision=standard -O2  -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/include/python2.7  -I. -I./ -IC:/pgsql96/include/server -IC:/pgsql96/include/internal -I/c/Builds/postgresql/source/src/include/port/win32 -DEXEC_BACKEND  -IC:/pgsql96/include/server/port/win32  -c -o src/errors.o src/errors.c
make: *** [<builtin>: src/errors.o] Error 1
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
PATH="/c/pgsql96/bin:$PATH" make
```

Comment: It tells me:  -bash: ./configure: No such file or directory.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `make`.

Comment: I had to add it to /c/msys64/mingw64/bin directory, so I used this command in mingw bin directory

    PATH="/c/pgsql95/bin:$PATH

The problem is solved now, thanks

Comment: this problem was fixed after I set the Path of pgsql95 in my mingw bin directory, but I have another error now,  which says : pythonpython:-config : Command not found, have any idea? (I updated the question)

Comment: Well, install it and tell the configuration process where it is.

Comment: I installed Python 2.7 and set the path to the configuration process. However, another issue pops up! I updated the question.

Comment: Thank you Laurenz Albe, sorry if my question might be too obvious for you.

Comment: Do you get an error if you `touch directories.stamp` by hand?

Comment: its just empty and does not let me to modify. I gave up on using multicorn on windows... if you have time can you explain about how to best compile Multicorn package, I dont see any good resources maybe as an answer to this question for future users. what do you suggest?

Comment: There's the problem. Change the file and ddirectory permissions so that the user building the software can modify the file. In general, it is tough to build PostgreSQL extensions on Windows. You might be best off asking the author of Multicorn.